# What does "typename..." mean in this context?

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I found some code in cppreference.com that I don't understand.
Here is the link: [Type Alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias). It's talking about `dependent template-id` which I don't understand.
Here's the code:

```
//When the result of specializing an alias template is a dependent template-id, 
//subsequent substitutions apply to that template-id:

template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
template<typename T>
void_t<typename T::foo> f();
f<int>();     // error, int does not have a nested type foo
```

When I hover over it on VS 2019 it says
`void_t<<`unnamed`>...>`

Can anyone explain to me how is this unnamed typename useful?

Comment: It's a template pack without name because it's not used. You can pass any types and the result  will be the same.

Comment: That was quick, thanks!

Comment: `std::void_t` (as `std::enable_if `) is mainly use for SFINAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain,
Expression `template<typename...> using void_t = void;` with type deduced to `void` irrespective of passed template parameter.
example,

```
template<typename...>
   using void_t = void;

template <typename T>
void_t<T> fun1() {
    std::cout << "fun1 called" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    fun1<int>();   //fun1 called
    fun1<float>(); //fun1 called
}
```

To extend the same, `template<typename T>void_t<typename T::foo> f();` only accepts `typename T` which has nested type `T::foo`. For example,

```
template<typename...> 
   using void_t = void;

template<typename T>
        void_t<typename T::foo> f() {}

struct bar
{
    typedef int foo;
};
int main() {
    f<bar>(); //Valid expression as bar::foo is nested type of bar
    f<int>(); //Error because `int::foo`is not a nested type of `int`.
}
```

For more information refer [Substitution failure is not an error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

Answer (score 4):

It's a template pack without name because it's not used. You can pass any types and the result will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

It allows you to pass template arguments to it and it will just *eat up* all the arguments, resulting in the same type. It is useful for SFINAE